# Do immigration officers have access who paid for your ticket?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, standard-visitor-visas

I always ask my friend to help me book my flight through his expedia account. We use his credit card for booking. But the receipt in expedia is under my name. Do immigration officers have information which credit card was used to book the ticket?

Comment: Why do you ask? Do you plan on lying to immigration about how you're financing your trip?

Answer (score 11):

There’s too much variation between countries to make a blanket statement. Airlines are required to send their passenger records to immigration ahead of time and its likely that at the very least, it indicates whether it’s a one way or return ticket and whether cash was used.

But it’s rather moot because if there’s any question at all, the immigration officer can simply ask the traveler:

- Who bought your ticket?

If the traveler  responds, “I did” then they would be asked to show proof and the provenance of funds. If they say someone else did, then the question is why did that person do so? Where did those funds come from?

It’s best to always assume that the immigration officers know the truth and to tell the truth so you aren’t caught in a lie. The officers are trained to look for signs of deception and their questions are designed to see if you’re telling the truth.

Comment: I can only agree, I just wrote up the golden rules of dealing with immigration in another question and we have repeated this all over the site again and again: Never lie to immigration. Never offer information unasked. Stay calm.